# Jquery code to match input value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to write a jquery code that will match input of user once they enter @ it will show that they key in @.
With this code am not getting any thing please someone should help me with that?

**HTML**

```
<input id="input" value=""/>
<div id="out"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var value = "@";
     $('#input').keyup(function(e) {
     //$('#input').match(value){
     $('#input').val=(value) {
             //alert('You enter @');
    $('#out').html("You enter @");     
         }
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage `.val()` is a not correct, its a function not a property. Note the code below is for exact match.

```
var value = "@";
$('#input').keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == value) {
        $('#out').html("You enter @");
    }

    //You can also use the value property like 
    //if (this.value == value) {
    //    $('#out').html("You enter @");
    //}
});
```

```js
var value = "@";
$('#input').keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == value) {
        $('#out').html("You enter @");
    }

    //You can also use the value property like 
    //if (this.value == value) {
    //    $('#out').html("You enter @");
    //}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" value=""/>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if($('#input').val() === value))
```

instead of

```
if($('#input').val=(value))
```